# Связанные поля со списком

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Пытаюсь сделать связанные поля со списком со значениями из базы данных, но возникла трудность.
html код полей:

```
<?php
require('scripts/connect.php');
$query = mysqli_query($link,"select name from category where level=1");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
echo "<select name='id_category' id='id_category'>";
echo "<option value='0'>- выберите категорию -</option>";
for($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++)
{
$mas = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo "<option value='".($i+1)."'>".$mas["name"]."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>

<select name="id_category_2" id="id_category_2" disabled="disabled" class="StyleSelectBox">
<option value="0">- выберите категорию -</option>
</select>
```

Код jQuery для функций выборы селекторов:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_category').change(function () {
        var id_category = $(this).val();
        if (id_category == '0') {
            $('#id_category_2').html('<option>- выберите регион -</option>');
            $('#id_category_2').attr('disabled', true);
            return(false);
        }
        $('#id_category_2').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#id_category_2').html('<option>загрузка...</option>');
        var url = "get_category.php";
        $.get(
            url,
            "id_category=" + id_category,
            function (result) {
                if (result.type == 'error') {
                    alert('error');
                    return(false);
                }
                else {      
                    var options = '';

                    $(result.id_category_2).each(function() {
                        options += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('id_category_2') + '">' + $(this).attr('name') + '</option>';
                    });
                    $('#id_category_2').html('<option value="0">- выберите категорию -</option>'+options);
                    $('#id_category_2').attr('disabled', false);
                }
            },
            "json"
        );
    });
});
```

Код файла php для выбора категорий:

```
<?php
include_once('connect.php');
$id_category = @intval($_GET['id_category']);
echo $id_category;
$cats=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id_category, name, pid FROM category WHERE pid=($id_category)");

if ($cats) {
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($cats);     
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $num) {
       $id_category_2[$i] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cats);  
       $i++;
    }    
    $result = array('id_category_2'=>$id_category_2); 
}
else {
    $result = array('type'=>'error');
}
print json_encode($result);
?>
```

При выборе категории поле остаётся неактивным, но даже если убрать выключение селекта, то так и висит "загрузка" и список не заполняется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте включать/выключать ваш второй селект не через `.attr('disabled', false);` , а через `.prop('disabled', false);`

Либо удаляйте атрибут вообще `.removeAttr('disabled');`

Comment: Дело не в этом, даже если включить селект, то список не заполняется, так и висит загрузка

Comment: Значит у вас не отрабатывает блок else{} в результатах $.get. Внутри $(result.id_category_2).each(function() { выведите полученные результаты.

Comment: Полученных результатов нет, переменная options не заполняется, насколько я понимаю.